# Why OpenSSL is not detected when configuring curl?

Tags: ubuntu, curl

I install the curl on the ubuntu 18.04 using cross complier(arm-linux-gnueabihf)

The OpenSSL detection error was occurred when I configure curl like the following

```
./configure --prefix=/etc/compile_curl --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --with-zlib=/etc/compile_zlib --with-ssl=/etc/compile_openssl
```

The following is the error message.

```
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable debug build options... no
checking whether to enable compiler optimizer... (assumed) yes
checking whether to enable strict compiler warnings... no
checking whether to enable compiler warnings as errors... no
checking whether to enable curl debug memory tracking... no
checking whether to enable hiding of library internal symbols... yes
checking whether to enable c-ares for DNS lookups... no
checking whether to disable dependency on -lrt... (assumed no)
checking whether to enable ECH support... no
checking for path separator... :
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for grep... /bin/grep
checking that grep -E works... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar... no
checking for ar... /usr/bin/ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for stdatomic.h... yes
checking if _Atomic is available... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for code coverage support... no
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking curl version... 8.4.0
checking for httpd... no
checking for apache2... no
checking for apachectl... no
checking for apxs... no
configure: httpd/apache2 not in PATH, http tests disabled
configure: apxs not in PATH, http tests disabled
checking for nghttpx... no
checking for caddy... no
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... (cached) /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking if OS is AIX (to define _ALL_SOURCE)... no
checking if _THREAD_SAFE is already defined... no
checking if _THREAD_SAFE is actually needed... no
checking if _THREAD_SAFE is onwards defined... no
checking if _REENTRANT is already defined... no
checking if _REENTRANT is actually needed... no
checking if _REENTRANT is onwards defined... no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-dumpbin... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-link... no
checking for dumpbin... no
checking for link... link -dump
checking the name lister (nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-file... no
checking for file... file
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump... no
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-dlltool... no
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar... /usr/bin/ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse nm output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-mt... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries with -version-info... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries with -no-undefined... no
checking whether to build shared libraries with -mimpure-text... no
checking whether to build shared libraries with PIC... yes
checking whether to build static libraries with PIC... no
checking whether to build shared libraries only... no
checking whether to build static libraries only... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-windres... no
checking for windres... no
checking for inline... inline
checking if cpp -P is needed... yes
checking if cpp -P works... yes
checking if compiler is DEC/Compaq/HP C... no
checking if compiler is HP-UX C... no
checking if compiler is IBM C... no
checking if compiler is Intel C... no
checking if compiler is clang... no
checking if compiler is GNU C... yes
checking if compiler is LCC... no
checking if compiler is SGI MIPSpro C... no
checking if compiler is SGI MIPS C... no
checking if compiler is SunPro C... no
checking if compiler is Tiny C... no
checking if compiler accepts some basic options... yes
configure: compiler options added: -Werror-implicit-function-declaration 
checking if compiler optimizer assumed setting might be used... yes
checking if compiler accepts optimizer enabling options... yes
configure: compiler options added: -O2
checking if compiler accepts strict warning options... yes
configure: compiler options added: -Wno-system-headers 
checking if compiler halts on compilation errors... yes
checking if compiler halts on negative sized arrays... yes
checking if compiler halts on function prototype mismatch... yes
checking if compiler supports hiding library internal symbols... yes
checking for windows.h... no
checking whether build target is a native Windows one... no
checking whether build target supports WIN32 file API... no
checking whether build target supports WIN32 crypto API... no
checking for good-to-use Darwin CFLAGS... no
checking whether to link macOS CoreFoundation, CoreServices, and SystemConfiguration frameworks... no
checking to see if the compiler supports __builtin_available()... no
checking whether to support http... yes
checking whether to support ftp... yes
checking whether to support file... yes
checking whether to support ldap... yes
checking whether to support ldaps... yes
checking whether to support rtsp... yes
checking whether to support proxies... yes
checking whether to support dict... yes
checking whether to support telnet... yes
checking whether to support tftp... yes
checking whether to support pop3... yes
checking whether to support imap... yes
checking whether to support smb... yes
checking whether to support smtp... yes
checking whether to support gopher... yes
checking whether to support mqtt... no
checking whether to provide built-in manual... yes
checking whether to enable generation of C code... yes
checking whether to use libgcc... no
checking if X/Open network library is required... no
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for windows.h... (cached) no
checking for winsock2.h... (cached) no
checking for proto/bsdsocket.h... no
checking for connect in libraries... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for monotonic clock_gettime... yes
checking for clock_gettime in libraries... no additional lib required
checking if monotonic clock_gettime works... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/time.h... (cached) yes
checking for raw monotonic clock_gettime... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking for gzread in -lz... no
configure: WARNING: configure found only the libz header file, not the lib!
checking for BrotliDecoderDecompress in -lbrotlidec... no
checking for brotli/decode.h... no
checking for ZSTD_createDStream in -lzstd... no
checking for zstd.h... no
checking for lber.h... no
checking for ldap.h... no
checking for ldap_ssl.h... no
checking for LDAP libraries... cannot find LDAP libraries
configure: WARNING: Cannot find libraries for LDAP support: LDAP disabled
checking whether to enable IPv6... yes
checking if struct sockaddr_in6 has sin6_scope_id member... yes
checking if argv can be written to... yes
checking if GSS-API support is requested... no
checking whether to enable Windows native SSL/TLS... no
checking whether to enable Secure Transport... no
checking whether to enable Amiga native SSL/TLS (AmiSSL v5)... no
configure: PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR will be set to "/etc/compile_openssl/lib/pkgconfig"
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config... no
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for HMAC_Update in -lcrypto... no
checking for HMAC_Init_ex in -lcrypto... no
checking OpenSSL linking with -ldl... no
checking OpenSSL linking with -ldl and -lpthread... no
configure: OPT_OPENSSL: /etc/compile_openssl
configure: OPENSSL_ENABLED: 
configure: error: --with-openssl was given but OpenSSL could not be detected
```

The openssl directroy places in the /etc/compile_openssl.

```
ls /etc/compile_openssl/bin
c_rehash  openssl
```

Is there any error in the configure option?

Thanks

Comment: Off: You shouldn't install components for foreign architectures into `/etc/`. For example, you could create directory `/usr/local/arm-linux-gnueabihf`